# IOS Chat app with back end .NET server

Tags: ios, asp.net, chat

i am developing a ios app in which i need to create instant text chat with a back end .net server.

And in future also use this server through my andropid app.

how can i achieve this goal ?

Comment: I can see that you never given someone the check mark. So when someone answers your question on stackoverflow and it is correct, like mine is, click the check mark next to the question to signify that it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use signalR with your .net backend. SignalR is a library that handles persistent socket connects via websocket, serversent, long polling etc.  Research SignalR and you will find plenty of examples and implementations.  Your IOS application can import the Obj-c SignalR client.  The client understands the protocol used to communicate with the server.

It's pretty basic and easy stuff to implement.

SignalR .Net
http://www.asp.net/signalr

Objective-c Client
https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC

Comment: I have not tested this till now. thats why i had not check.

Comment: Now i have look on all things , And get that library